# Use of random() in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, random, io, output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
const int lim=4;
int main(){
    randomize();
    int p;
    p=100+random(lim);
    for(int i=p;i>=100;i--){
     cout<<i<<"#";  
    }
    cout<<endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I do not get any output . Am I not supposed get an output here ? Can anyone tell me what's wrong ?

Comment: Maybe i and also p are already smaller than 100

Comment: C++ doesn't have a `randomize` or `random` function.

Comment: I got this question on a C++ Finals today. The question asked us to predict 1 possible output of the above code. Moreover, how can it be that C++ doesn't have such a function and yet the code compiles ?

Comment: @Monk, It can't (portably). There's probably an extra header with those functions defined that you didn't include here.

Comment: @chris I did include the entire code - I compiled it with g++ using codelite IDE.

Comment: The compiler could still implicitly include some headers in a directory. Have a look at the official contents of the `<random>` header. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random
If you insist on wanting that code to work, then you need to look into whatever the compiler included in your program.

Comment: What standard-library are you including? Does it (non-conformingly) define those symbols?

Comment: @Deduplicator, Is it really non-conforming? They're all in `std`.

Comment: @chris: `randomize` is not to be found in the C++14 standard, neither is a function named `random`.

Comment: @Deduplicator, Yes, but how is exposing something extra within `std` not allowed? The point of namespaces is that it won't affect proper outside code. I do admit it would be unwise for an implementation to expose something that isn't a reserved identifier, but is it really not allowed?

Comment: There's a `getch` in curses, but no corresponding include. This code just doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Functions `random` and `randomize` do not even exist in the `<random>` header. They MIGHT exist in your working environment, who knows what the compiler could implicitly include, but nevertheless, it's not standard C++.

Instead, create a random number device (this will give you `randomize()`), have a PRNG of your choice (containing the number generation algorithm), then create a uniform integer distribution (in that case you might want between 100 and 103, in which either one of these numbers can occur: 100, 101, 102 or 103).

```
random_device rd;
minstd_rand gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(100, 103);
```

Then generate a number like this:

```
int p = dis(gen);
```